# How can I make JAX-RS uri encode the response

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Is there a method to make JAX-RS call the Java equivalent of Javascript's encodeURI on the return? For example, let's say I have this class:

```
public Class MyResponse {
 public String greeting;
}
```

And this sample method:

```
@GET
@Path("response")
public MyResponse getResponse {
 MyResponse rtn = new MyResponse();
 rtn.greeting = "<b>Hello!</b>";
 return rtn;
}
```

Normally this would return the following JSON:

```
{
 greeting: "<b>Hello!</b>"
}
```

I would like a cross-cutting way to instead have the following returned:

```
{
 greeting: "%3Cb%3EHello!%3C/b%3E"
}
```

By cross-cutting I mean I don't want to have to hand-specify which fields to encode -- I would like *all* String fields to get this treatment.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html), which encodes given `string`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question, which was how this operation can be applied to all fields on an Object automatically.